# How to open the Screenshot Folder right after taking the screenshot

Tags: macos, automator, screen-capture

I've changed the folder to which Screenshots are saved on the MacOS (This explains how it is done - http://www.idownloadblog.com/2014/06/15/how-to-change-where-screenshots-are-saved-on-mac/).

I was wondering if I can create an Automator script / Workflow so that this custom folder, say `~/Screenshots`, automatically opens up immediately after the screenshot is taken. (For reference, I want it to behave like the Chrome Fireshot extension).

Comment: Two things come to mind. You could replace the default screenshot hotkeys with custom automator services. [Something like in the answers here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/8022/126929) and then add "Get specified Finder items" + "Reveal Finder items". Or.. [EventScripts](http://mousedown.net/mouseware/EventScripts.html) can trigger scripts when a screenshot is taken.

Answer (score 5):

Save this script as "Reveal_Screenshot.scpt", In Script Editor to your /Users/INSERT YOUR USERNAME/Library/Workflows/Applications/Folder Actions folder.

```
on adding folder items to theFolder after receiving theNewItems
    --  Called after items have been added to a folder
    --  theFolder is a reference to the modified folder
    --  theNewItems is a list of references to the items added to the folder 
    tell application "Finder"
        activate
        reveal theNewItems
    end tell
end adding folder items to
```

Now add a folder action to your ~/Screenshots folder in Finder.app by control + click on ~/Screenshots folder

[image]

Because you saved that script in the previous step, it will now be available to choose as a folder action to attach to your folder

[image]

Now every time a screen shot gets added to your ~/Screenshots folder , it will bring Finder.app to the front and reveal the new file in your folder